# Spring MVC: the content of uploaded multipartFile is unreadable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a test xlsx file with one line of random data:

```
A     | B      |  C       | D

Test1 |  Test2 |  Test3   | Test4
```

Then I use the following command to upload this test file to my spring controller.

```
curl -k -F file=@/Users/username/Desktop/test.xlsx https://server-name:8303/rpl/spreadsheet/getasinlimits
```

But when I try to log the conntent of file, **all I get is a bunch of unreadable character.**

At first I thought it is because encoding, I try to use `String line = new String(multipartFile.getBytes(), "UTF-8")`, but still the same.

I have a few log info here, the results I get:

> 117   <---------   lines.size() . , why 117 ????? I only have one line in the file.
>
> file  <----------- multipartFile.getName()
>
> test.xlsx . <-------------- multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()

**Can anyone please tell me why I am having 117 lines? And why is the content unreadable character?**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rpl/spreadsheet/getasinlimits", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public BGCServiceResponseStatus getAsinLimit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile) {


        List<String> lines = parseMultipartFileLinebyLine(multipartFile);

        logger.info(Integer.toString(lines.size()));            
        logger.info(multipartFile.getName());
        logger.info(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());

        return new BGCServiceResponseStatus(ResponseCode.OK, "{\"status\": \"OK.\"}");
    }


    private List<String> parseMultipartFileLinebyLine(MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        BufferedReader br;
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!multipartFile.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String line;
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(multipartFile.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: Your parsing method is reading lines, thats identified by EOL character.... the xlsx may have different format. Try using some library for parsing xlss files.

Comment: Is it a text file or an actual xls file? Opening an xls file in a text editor shouldn't work quite right for you either. If it is an xls file, then that is a binary file and I imagine you should be reading bytes from the input stream and writing them to the output stream if you just want to save it. Otherwise you might want use a library like http://poi.apache.org/